# How to write the code in Oracle SQL (like 'CCYYMMDD' into 102 )

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to write the code in `Oracle SQL` (like `'CCYYMMDD'` into `102` )?
If someone will enter the date in the frontend, the value should return as `102` instead of date.
For that, how will write the function in `Oracle PLSQL`.

https://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/d00a/tred/tred2379.htm
These are the ANSI standard format.

Comment: It's the first time I see this "standard". Usually [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is used.

Comment: So you want to Oracle date format code to be returned, when a date in any format is given as input? The problem is dates like `080706`, which can mean different dates: Aug 7th 2006, or 8th of July 2008, or is it 1908?

Comment: Please clarify your question: do you want to display a date in any format to this specific format? Or do you want to analyse an input string and say which of these "standard" formats it fits?

Comment: @jarlh being from Sweden I read your example as 6th of July 2008 :) To OP, isn't it simpler to implement some restrictions in the front-end as to what can be entered? It will be impossible to write bullet-proof code.

Comment: have you already tried `select to_char(sysdate,'CCYYMMDD') from dual` ..?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, forgot that one, so silly of me (another Swede.)

Comment: yes, I already tried, but we want in this standard. 
102   CCYYMMDD
Calendar date: C = Century ; Y = Year ; M = Month ; D =Day.

Comment: In Front End, we want this value as output but Insertion should be always in date format.
<transmissiondateformat>102</transmissiondateformat> 
so, for that, how to write the code in SQL for the particular column.

Comment: If anyone inserts the date in this format "CCYYMMDD"  in the frontend then return should be as a default value 102. 
For that, how to write the code in Oracle SQL for a particular format change to the default value(102).

Comment: The only way to do this is to strictly enforce date format in the front-end input. Use a date picker widget or separate input boxes for year, month and day. Any other approach will be doomed to data corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify that a string fits a date format like this:

```
create or replace function is_CCYYMMDD 
    (p_str in varchar2)
    return boolean
is
    rv boolean;
    dt date;
begin
    begin
        dt := to_date(p_str, 'YYYYMMDD');
        dt := to_date('2000' || substr(p_str, 5), 'YYYYMMDD');
        rv := true; 
    exception
        when others then
            rv := false;
    end;
    return rv;
end;
```

The first `to_date()` just checks that the whole string is a valid date. The second `to_date()` checks that the second half of the string is a valid month and day combo. This partly addresses [@MTO observations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516168/146325) about the problems of enforcing a strict format when some strings can fit more than one format.

Note that it is perfectly possible to have valid dates which pass this test despite  being ambiguous e.g. is `20111012` in `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'DDMMYYYY'`? There is no way to be sure unless you enforce strict date formatting in the front-end input by using a date picker widget or separate input boxes for year, month and day.

> why you pass '2000' in this query?

The second check verifies that the last four characters are valid as month and day. Whenever we do this sort of test we run into the problem of leap years. If we just apply `to_date(str, 'MMDD')` Oracle will default the year to the current year: the snag is `2018029` is not a valid date even though the original input of `20160229` is valid. My function avoids this by fixing the year element to 2000, which was a leap year.

---

Incidentally, if you want to use this function in SQL you'll need to change the return datatype to varchar2 (Y/N flag) or a number (1/0) because SQL doesn't support Booolean.

Comment: why you pass '2000' in this query:dt := to_date('2000' || substr(p_str, 5), 'MMDD');
        rv := true;

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write a function to determine which numeric date string corresponds to which format as the date string could be multiple formats:

For example, `010203` could be:

- Format 2: `DDMMYY` 1st February 03
- Format 3: `MMDDYY` 2nd January 03
- Format 101: `YYMMDD` 3rd February 01
- Format 306: `DDHHMM` 02:03 of Day 1
- Format 402: `HHMMSS` 01:02:03
- Format 405: `MMMMSS` 102 minutes 3 seconds
- Format 610: `CCYYMM` March 0102
- Format 616: `CCYYWW` Week 3 of 0102

Similarly `10080102` could be:

- Format 4: `DDMMCCYY` 10th August 102
- Format 102: `CCYYMMDD` 2nd January 1008
- Format 305: `MMDDHHMM` 8th October 01:02
- Format 501: `HHMMHHMM` Time span from 10:08 to 01:01

> If anyone inserts the date in this format "CCYYMMDD" then the value should return only 102 as a default in the frontend. How to write the code in SQL?

You cannot, as I described above it is ambiguous what some values are and they could return multiple formats. Instead you should create another column and store the date format in that when the user inputs the date rather than trying to reconstruct the format code from an (ambiguous) number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an Oracle date into a Julian date, then you can use the TO_CHAR function with 'j' as the format.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('BC47120412', 'BCYYYYMMDD'), 'J')
  FROM DUAL;

Output: 0000102
```

If you want to convert julian date to oracle date then use query below,

```
SELECT TO_DATE(102, 'J') 
  FROM DUAL;

Output: 04/12/4712 12:00:00 AM BC
```

Comment: The `J` format model is for Julian Date and counts the number of days since `-4712-11-23`. This does not appear to be what the question was asking.

Comment: Its ok, this is for the particular date but we want if anyone inserts the date in this format "CCYYMMDD"
then the value should return only 102 as a default in the frontend. 
How to write the code in SQL?

<transmissiondateformat>102</transmissiondateformat> (THIS IS THE COLUMN NAME transmissiondateformat & I have to create a function for that).

Comment: @adityakumar `SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( '20081128', 'YYYYMMDD' ), 'J' ) FROM DUAL;` outputs `2454799` not `102` as you appear to want.

Comment: Ok, how can we get as a default value 102 only?
102 
ANSI 
2 = yy.mm.dd
102 = yyyy.mm.dd

Comment: @adityakumar You cannot. Is `20081112` format 102 (`CCYYMMDD`) or format 4 (`DDMMCCYY`)?

Comment: @MT0, i was just guessing what he needs,

Comment: @adityakumar, does 102 has an equivalent date? is 102 = 01/01/2018 or what date?

Comment: All dates in the format `YYYYMMDD` should output `102`, all dates in the format `DDMMYYYY` should output `4`. The problem is when a date could be either format then it is ambiguous which result should be output which is why the OP's requested solution of a function will not work for all inputs.